# Moving heat from a 1st floor wood stove to the basement

Tags: basement, heating, woodstove

I have a new woodburning stove on the 1st floor of my home and would like to maximize the distribution of the heat. I wondered if I installed a fan similar to an exhaust fan behind the woodstove using a 4" venting pipe through the wall down to the basement, would that pull heat down.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Would use duck work and pull the heat from near the ceiling, not the floor.  Heat rises so the hottest air will be near the ceiling, before it cools down and falls to the floor.

Comment: Maybe use a duct booster fan instead of an exhaust fan.  they fit into ducts.

Comment: If you have an air handler for furnace or A/C you can set it to fan-only mode.  That may not serve the basement though.  Your idea is a good one but do as @crip659 says, take heat from near the ceiling, pump it into a cold part of the basement far from the stairs, and you need to leave the basement door open if you have one so air can circulate back up to the area of the stove.  Don't imagine yourself "pumping heat" to the basement.  Imagine yourself creating a circular path and getting air to flow along it.

Comment: @crip659 You use “duck work” ? (Darn autocorrect. Happened to me once too.)

Answer (score 1):

I've done this successfully with a wood stove to move heat from one room to another. Since heat rises you'll ideally want to move the heat from the wall near the ceiling above the wood stove and run it through ductwork to the lower floor releasing it at floor level away from the stairwell.
There are some excellent in-line quiet fans that would work well for this type of application.
You can set it up for either manual or thermostatic control.

Comment: I wonder if you could feed the oven cool air up from he basement thru its air intake, and then have a separate pipe thru the same hole in the floor where hot air from outside the stove will flow down because of relatively lower basement pressure (because of pulling air from basement into stove)